# Average volleyball athlete height in NCAA

Tags: trivia, volleyball

What's the average height of the male and female volleyball athletes by position and division in the NCAA?

Answer (score 3):

These are the average volleyball heights for an athlete according to their positions:

> [Libero/Defensive Specialist:](http://www.ncsasports.org/recruiting-tools/college-volleyball-recruiting/volleyball-recruiting-guidelines/volleyball-libero) 5'5" - 6'0" *(165.1 - 182.9 cm)*
>
> [Middle Blocker](http://www.ncsasports.org/recruiting-tools/college-volleyball-recruiting/volleyball-recruiting-guidelines/volleyball-middle-blocker): 6'0" - 6'4"+ *(182.9 - 193+ cm)*
>
> [Outside Hitters](http://www.ncsasports.org/recruiting-tools/college-volleyball-recruiting/volleyball-recruiting-guidelines/volleyball-outside-hitter): 5'11" - 6'2" *(180.3 - 188 cm)*
>
> [Rightside Hitters](http://www.ncsasports.org/recruiting-tools/college-volleyball-recruiting/volleyball-recruiting-guidelines/volleyball-rightside-hitter): 5'11" - 6'2"+ *(180.3 - 188+ cm)*
>
> [Setters](http://www.ncsasports.org/recruiting-tools/college-volleyball-recruiting/volleyball-recruiting-guidelines/volleyball-setter): 5'9" - 6'1"+ *(175.3 - 185.4+ cm)*

Comment: I added the information from the link that addresses the OP's question. Link-only [answers](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are [discouraged](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: This is good, but the question specifically asked for male and female. I'm wondering do female middle blockers also tend to be over 6'0"?

Answer (score 1):

For men, I found similar stats from the same source as women in the other answer, but scattered over different pages:

- [Setter](https://www.ncsasports.org/recruiting-tools/mens-high-school-volleyball/mens-volleyball-recruiting-guidelines/mens-volleyball-setter): 6'1" - 6'5"
- [Libero](https://www.ncsasports.org/recruiting-tools/mens-high-school-volleyball/mens-volleyball-recruiting-guidelines/mens-libero): 5'8" - 6'2"
- [Outside Hitter](https://www.ncsasports.org/recruiting-tools/mens-high-school-volleyball/mens-volleyball-recruiting-guidelines/mens-volleyball-outside-hitter): 6'3" - 6'6"

---

And for comparison to international play, I also found [this from the FIVB, based on the 2012 Olympics](http://www.fivb.org/en/technical/olympics/2012/men/Misc/Personal%20Data.htm):

Height of the top 4 teams per player function

Volleyball coaches often discuss about the importance to select tall players. In overview two tables with some facts about this subject. First an overview of the height of players for the top 4 teams OG 2012 London by player function:
[image: London 2012 Men's volleyball player heights by position for top 4 finishing teams]